# Enable compiler warnings for implicit conversions (C#)

Tags: c#, compiler-warnings, implicit-conversion

Is there any way to enable compiler warnings for implicit conversions in C#?

Recently been debugging for over an hour until I realized I had the following code:

```
double = int / int;
```

which didn't quite work as intended. Compiler does not show any warning for it, even at warning level 4. I'm working with Microsoft Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: no... because there is really nothing wrong in such code from compiler's point of view.

Comment: The implicit conversion from int to double was not your problem; it was the integer division which lost you your precision.

Answer (score 2):

This "problem" is much more of a heuristics issue.

In effect your code was doing the following.

```
int numerator = ...;
int denominator = ...;
int integerDivide = numerator / denominator;
double result = integerDivide;
```

At no point was there anything that the compiler should flag as an error. Sure you COULD treat the whole as a warning, but its not in the spirit of how compilers work.

It is possible to add this as a warning on some kind of productivity tool, like Resharper or Roslyn. But it would NEVER be added to the core compiler.

Comment: I understand what the compiler is seeing and that the error happened with the division, but the problem would also not exist if I wanted `result` to be an `int`. The fact is that the compiler implicitly converted an `int` to a `double` and no matter the situation, I'd like a warning for that. C++ compilers do warn users for every implicit conversion from and to basic types.

Answer (score 1):

C# already warns about a ridiculous number of safe conversion, but as others observe, it does appear that you are really looking for automatic detection of integer (truncating) division.  Unfortunately, it's the same `DIV` opcode in MSIL, so you need type analysis to detect it.  Not impossible, but non-trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because assigning the value of an int to a double doesn't require a conversion. If you try the opposite:

```
double a = 5;
int b = a;
```

You get a "cannot implicitly convert double to int" error. But if you try what you were doing:

```
int a = 5;
double b = a;
```

It works ok.

A double has a higher maximum (and presumably lower minimum) than an int, so there's no conversion necessary, so you shouldn't experience any side effects of assigning a double an int, so there's no need for an error. I notice that even with the strictest rule set enabled the code analysis tool in vs2013 doesn't even raise an eyebrow.

Comment: No, the rule is NOT "the result of the divide will be what you are dividing by".  Division of a double by an int also results in a double.

Comment: Well, I'll be jiggered, you're right.